# I am having some C# and Unity Confusion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[here is the code that I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v282Y.png)

[Here is the error code from unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9HKW.png)

Comment: that is just code. what is the error?

Comment: I had to edit the post bc I am new to this website I fixed the post now but I am getting error code cs0103

Comment: Don't post images of code. Post the code itself

Comment: To make a good question: post code as string, indicate what and where is the error you have, also, give it a meaningful title.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read about how to ask good questions, as well as this question checklist. Lastly please learn how to create a minimal reproducible example to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos in the code. you write `keycode.DownArrow` but it must be `KeyCode.DownArrow`.

Also you write `input` once. It must be `Input`.

Comment: Thank you, This worked I was going to give up, but now I just feel very stupid

Comment: Have you ever read the error you posted?